# ExpandableListView callbacks not synchronized

Tags: android, listview, synchronization, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I'm extending an ExpandableListView to create my own listview and the adapter callbacks are implemented in the following way:

```
@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return m_FilteredSites.getSize();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int i) {
    return m_FilteredSites.get(i);
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    SiteEntity site = (SiteEntity) getGroup(groupPosition);
    //more code ....
}
```

The problem is that in between the calls to getGroupCount and getGroupView, the m_FilteredSites collection can change (due to filter being used in my case).
Is there a way to enforce synchronization or any other method that will keep the data consistent between calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is now fixed.
The problem was that I was changing the m_FilteredSites collection on a worker thread instead of the UI thread.
The Filter class has 2 callbacks:
1. performFiltering - which is executed on a worker thread.
2. publishResults - which is executed on the UI thread.

Initially I was calculating the filter but also modifying the m_FilteredSites on the performFiltering method.
The fix is to move the actual code that changes the m_FilteredSites collection to the publishResults  method.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You shouldn't change the internal data outside of [`setAdapter()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setAdapter%28android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter%29)</strike>. Instead, you can build new adapter, then change it with that method, and everything will be fine.

This video is for `ListView`, but it works with `ExpandableListView` too: [Google I/O 2010 - The world of ListView](http://youtu.be/wDBM6wVEO70). If you have time, I think it's worth watching.

---

*Edited*

I'm sorry I couldn't remember where I learned that. I've just re-watched the video above but couldn't find that moment. I think `notifyDataSetChanged()` is used when data of the items in the list are changed, not the list itself. Now if I remember right, you should do this:

```
public class SampleAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private List<List<String>> mData;

    public void updateData(List<List<String>> data) {
        mData = data;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

I mean you shouldn't change items of `mData` (such as `add()`, `remove()`…). It's better to build new list and assign it to `mData` like above code.

If you have a [content provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html), you can use [`CursorTreeAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorTreeAdapter.html), it manages the data set automatically for you. I would highly recommend using content providers.

Comment: Your answer sounds reasonable. yet, doesn't the notifyDataSetChanged method in the adapter demonstrate that it is "ok" to change the internal data of an adapter without recreating it?

Answer (score 0):

You can synchronize your own code to access it sequentially instead of concurrently, e.g:

```
ExpandableListView elv;

synchronized(elv) {
    // Do whatever with elv that requires exclusive thread access
}
```

Comment: I don't see how synchronizing my code will help. I don't control the flow - these are system callbacks. The system for example will 1. call getGroupCount and get the number 3 (synchroinzation block ends). 2. now I change the data in another synchronizaed block and the number of items changes to 0. 3. now the system calls getGroupView with the number 2 because it still thinks that the number of items is 3. boom.